# Updating ValidationSummary Via Asynchronously - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, data-annotations, modelstate

In my controller, if the modelstate is invalid

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      return View();
```

I'd like to update the ValidationMessage but not have to repost the View.  Seems like a desirable concept with validation messages.  I'm using DataAnnotations as well that uses `<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>` but it still posts to the controller and I have to perform this check.  Any suggested implementations?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the view with the model.

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return View("Create", m);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but it sounds like you want the ValidationSummary to be displayed client side when errors exist without having to submit the form to the server. I ran into this a while ago and solved it in somewhat of an awkward manner with what was outlined in this post;

http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2010/02/27/asp.net-mvc-client-side-validation-summary-with-jquery-validation-plugin.aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: Previous link may be a little overkill... Check this out... http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/08/23/asp-net-mvc-jquery-validation-and-validationsummary.aspx